# "void is an invalid type for the variable paintSquare" error

Tags: java, variables, void, tetris

I'm making a Tetris clone for my AP Comp Sci class properly titled 'Titris' and while going through whatever errors there were I got this one. it came from this code

`private void paintSquare(Graphics g1, int x, int y) {
            Color  color = matrix[y][x];
            int    xMin = x * squareSize.width;
            int    yMin = y * squareSize.height;
            int    xMax = xMin + squareSize.width - 1;
            int    yMax = yMin + squareSize.height - 1;
            int    i;
    bufferRect.x = xMin;
            bufferRect.y = yMin;
            bufferRect.width = squareSize.width;
            bufferRect.height = squareSize.height;
            if (!bufferRect.intersects(g1.getClipBounds())) {
                return;
            }`

The error coming from `paintSquare`

Please help, this project is due soon & I don't know what to do about this error.

Comment: In the future you should include the errors from the compiler when asking about code that doesn't compile.

Comment: Why is there a semi colon after your method deceleration?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon after your argument list.

```
private void paintSquare(Graphics g1, int x, int y) {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void paintSquare(Graphics g1, int x, int y); {
```

should be

```
private void paintSquare(Graphics g1, int x, int y) {
```

The semicolon after the parameters is breaking your code.

Comment: give u +1 for explaining why the ; has to be removed

Comment: Still getting the same error after doing this.

Comment: @djdarkfiasco your logic must be wrong

Comment: Can you post all the code in that function please?

Comment: Updated w/ the whole code that the function's in